# Fourier transform and convolution of product of Heaviside and indicator of a ball

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Let $r > 0$ and $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and denote by $rB_n$ the ball of radius $r$ in $n$ dimensions. Consider the functions: $f_1(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{1}(\langle\mathbf{w},\mathbf{x}\rangle > 0)$ and $f_2(\mathbf{x})$ is the Fourier transform of the indicator of a ball with radius $r$ (This has an explicit formula in [Fourier transform of the indicator of the unit ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489391/fourier-transform-of-the-indicator-of-the-unit-ball)).

I want to calculate, or at least lower bound by some constant, the following integral:

$\int_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus 2rB_n}|\widehat{f_1f_2}(\mathbf{x})|^2d\mathbf{x}$

I am trying to calculate this integral using the convolution theorem, and without using the explicit formula for $f_2$. I basically need some closed form to: $|\widehat{f_1}*\widehat{f_2}|^2$.

First, since the integral is over a symmetric domain, we can assume w.l.o.g that $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{e_1}$. Now, we have that $\widehat{f_2}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{1}(\|{x}\| \leq r)$, and the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function is also known ([Fourier Transform of Heaviside Step Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764426/fourier-transform-of-heaviside-step-function)), but is given via a tempered distribution. The problem I am having is how to calculate this convolution. The thing is that $f_1f_2\in L_2 $ so it should have a Fourier transform in the standard sense, but calculating it requires doing a convolution with a tempered distribution which I'm not sure how to do.